# asp.net invalid path ending in slash does not return to error page IIS

Tags: iis, error-handling, configuration, server

Is there a specific setting in IIS to get the error page handling to work right if you enter a url that ends with "/"?  On my local machine, if I navigate to

http://localhost:20640/herbitty/blerb.aspx

OR

http://localhost:20640/herbitty/

http://localhost:20640/herbitty/?somehorriblequerystring=oops

These pages redirect to Default.aspx as they should.  But after i've deployed to the server, only the pages ending with .aspx work properly.  The pages ending with a slash end or a random static content (http://my.dev-server.org/ls/ls.html) up on a completely white page, with no html or anything.

Here is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Default.aspx" />       
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>

    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode='-1' />
      <remove statusCode="503" subStatusCode='-1' />
      <!-- this catches everything that is not Default.aspx-->
      <error statusCode="404" path="/Default.aspx" prefixLanguageFilePath="" responseMode="ExecuteURL"  />
      <!-- 503 needs to redirect because this is set manually on the Default.aspx page-->
      <error statusCode="503" path="/Default.aspx" prefixLanguageFilePath="" responseMode="ExecuteURL"  />
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

My server did not have the following roles added to it:

- Web Server -> Common HTTP Features -> HTTP Errors
- Web Server -> Common HTTP Features -> HTTP Redirection

Now I get a proper 404 error page, so i can now catch it.